# Convert datetime to valid JavaScript date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a datetime string being provided to me in the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
2011-07-14 11:23:00
```

When attempting to parse it into a JavaScript `date()` object it fails. What is the best way to convert this into a format that JavaScript can understand?

The answers below suggest something like

```
var myDate = new Date('2011-07-14 11:23:00');
```

Which is what I was using. It appears this may be a browser issue. I've made a http://jsfiddle.net/czeBu/ for this. It works OK for me in [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome). In Firefox 5.0.1 on OS X it returns `Invalid Date`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The failure is up to the browser implementation's handling of [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and how they allow for date strings not conform the [date standards](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format)

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format.
> The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

So we can force your string into this

```js
const getDateFromString = str => {
  const [date,time] = str.split(" ");
  // reformat string into YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
  str = `${date}T${time}.000Z`
  return new Date(str);
};
let date = getDateFromString('2011-07-14 11:23:00');
console.log(date)
```

---

Older answer:

As for your format, some OSX browsers insist on the dashes being slashes.

This works everywhere including Safari 5 and Firefox 5 on OS X.

UPDATE: Fx Quantum (54) has no need for the replace, but Safari 11 is still not happy unless you convert as below

```js
var date_test = new Date("2011-07-14 11:23:00".replace(/-/g,"/"));
console.log(date_test);
```

Comment: This is less invasive than the other solution I had, and it works well, thanks!

Comment: I agree :) I posted mine there too

Comment: How can i convert my this `2019-11-18T06:34:01.548Z` date format to simple date i.e `2019-11-18`. ?

Comment: `yourDate.split("T")[0]`

Answer (score 5):

One can use the getmonth and getday methods to get only the date.

Here I attach my solution:

```js
var fullDate = new Date(); console.log(fullDate);
var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth() + "";
if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1)
    twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;
var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + "";
if (twoDigitDate.length == 1)
    twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
var currentDate = twoDigitDate + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear(); console.log(currentDate);
```

Comment: You need to add 1 to getMonth to get the human readable date

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Date.parse()` which returns a Number, then use `new Date()` to parse it:

```
var thedate = new Date(Date.parse("2011-07-14 11:23:00"));
```

Comment: According to the docs, `new Date(Date.parse(dateString))` is the same as `new Date(dateString)`;

Comment: @Harmen: You seem to be correct. I was having some problems with doing it directly, but I can't remember what exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use moment.js for that, it will convert DateTime object into valid Javascript formated date:

```
   moment(DateOfBirth).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'); // put format as you want 

   Output: 28-Apr-1993
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
enter code var moment = require('moment')
var startDate = moment('2013-5-11 8:73:18', 'YYYY-M-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Moment.js works very well. You can read more about it [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function ConvertDateFromDiv(divTimeStr) {
    //eg:-divTimeStr=18/03/2013 12:53:00
    var tmstr = divTimeStr.toString().split(' '); //'21-01-2013 PM 3:20:24'
    var dt = tmstr[0].split('/');
    var str = dt[2] + "/" + dt[1] + "/" + dt[0] + " " + tmstr[1]; //+ " " + tmstr[1]//'2013/01/20 3:20:24 pm'
    var time = new Date(str);
    if (time == "Invalid Date") {
        time = new Date(divTimeStr);
    }
    return time;
}
```

Comment: At least replace '/' with '-' which is asked in the question.

Answer (score -1):

`new Date("2011-07-14 11:23:00");` works fine for me.

Comment: Yes and no. It works for me in Chrome, but run this in FF 5.0.1 http://jsfiddle.net/czeBu/ and it will return invalid date.

Comment: Dont work in firefox 28

Answer (score -1):

You can use get methods:

```js
var fullDate = new Date();
console.log(fullDate);
var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth() + "";
if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1)
    twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;
var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + "";
if (twoDigitDate.length == 1)
    twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
var currentDate = twoDigitDate + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear(); console.log(currentDate);
```

Comment: Since this is IDENTICAL to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39166405/295783) posted 2 minutes before, it has the same error of the month being off by one